# Adding a leaderboard and achievement to game in iOS with obj-c

Tags: ios, game-center

I need some basic help adding gamecenter leaderboard and a achievement to my game in iOS with Obj-C.

Comment: all the tutorials i've found are outdated.

Comment: This is a very broad "question" (I use that term very loosely).  Questions posted on this site should be much more specific--tell us what you have tried, what isn't working, errors you get, stuff like that.  Can you edit this to make it more focused?

Comment: I am having trouble getting gamecenter leaderboard and achievement in xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this? You do know that to enable game centre, you have to be able to create a place holder for your game in iTunes Connect?

[Integrating Game Centre](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-game-kit-framework/)

Comment: yes i have all that done. I just can't figure out the rest. even with reading the tutorials